# Update/Insert into mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to perform a update/insert into query for MySQL. Should insert, if not already in database.

However, it will not update. My db connection is good. I cannot figure it out.

```
$sql =  "UPDATE jos_bl_paid SET u_id='$uid', m_id = '$mid', t_id = '$cus', pd = '1', paypal_payment='$txn',p_date=NOW() WHERE u_id = '$uid' AND '$mid' = m_id ";            

$test45 = mysql_affected_rows();
  if ($test45 == 0) {


$sql = "INSERT INTO jos_bl_paid(paypal_payment,u_id,m_id,pd,t_id,p_date)VALUES('$txn','$uid','$mid','1','$cus',NOW())";

    if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
        error_log(mysql_error());
        exit(0);
                         }

echo 'Yes';
}else{
echo 'No';
}
```

Comment: **warning** your code maybe susceptible to sql injection attacks!

Comment: Use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` instead of separate `INSERT` and `UPDATE`. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code you are showing you aren't even running the update query.  You need to put

```
if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
    error_log(mysql_error());
    exit(0);
}
```

before the line

```
$test45 = mysql_affected_rows();
```

for that to even return what you want

Comment: Seems like that was the problem! Still running tests!

Comment: Also you should probably clean your variables to prevent sql injection like @Daniel said unless this is done before this section of code.  Also could be done better as @dfsq said in one statement with `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

Answer (score 0):

I would make these into one statement using the [ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) mysql command.  I would guess that your problem is that the insert may be failing because of some unique key set in you schema even though the actual uid doesn't yet exist so the update also fails. Can you post exactly what error message you get?

Answer (score 0):

check your last value in update query i found an error there and have fixed it from my side
try this

```
$sql =  mysql_query("UPDATE jos_bl_paid SET u_id='$uid',m_id = '$mid', t_id = '$cus', pd = '1', paypal_payment='$txn',p_date=NOW() WHERE u_id = '$uid' AND m_id = '$mid'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer is updated try the updated one

Answer (score 0):

From the code you posted, it appears that you're setting the `$sql` string to an update statement, but not executing it before checking for the number of affected rows.

You'll probably need to call `mysql_query($sql)` before checking `mysql_affected_rows();`

Otherwise you're not telling the database to update anything.

Answer (score 0):

If the new values in update are the same as old one mysql won't update the row and you will have `mysql_affected_rows` be 0. If you have primary key on fields `u_id`, `m_id` you can use `INSERT ON DUPLICATE UPDATE` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

If you don't have such you may use the count query:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM jos_bl_paid WHERE u_id = '$uid' AND '$mid' = m_id
```

To decide if you should update or insert new one.